# ssh root@192.168.1.1 Abort trap: 6 / MacOS / Catalina / SafeNet

Tags: macos, catalina, ssh

After upgrading from Mojave to Catalina I have the error while using ssh with /Library/Frameworks/eToken.framework/Versions/Current/libeToken.dylib :

```
Process:               ssh [5944]
Path:                  /usr/bin/ssh
Identifier:            ssh
Version:               3.0 (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [5937]
Responsible:           Terminal [706]
User ID:               501

PlugIn Path:             /Library/Frameworks/eToken.framework/Versions/A/libeToken.dylib
PlugIn Identifier:       libeToken.dylib
PlugIn Version:          ??? (0)

Date/Time:             2020-04-20 17:44:24.757 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.4 (19E287)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        51C57798-24F7-0370-506E-4F0310ED9038


Time Awake Since Boot: 2700 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
dyld3 mode
abort() called
Invalid dylib load. Clients should not load the unversioned libcrypto dylib as it does not have a stable ABI.

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff714fd33a __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff715b9e60 pthread_kill + 430
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff71484808 abort + 120
3   libcrypto.dylib                 0x00007fff6efaf804 __report_load + 404
4   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff713a06d2 invocation function for block in dyld3::AllImages::runAllInitializersInImage(dyld3::closure::Image const*, dyld3::MachOLoaded const*) + 159
5   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff713a05ae dyld3::closure::Image::forEachInitializer(void const*, void (void const*) block_pointer) const + 84
6   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff713a0325 invocation function for block in dyld3::AllImages::runInitialzersBottomUp(dyld3::closure::Image const*) + 349
7   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff713a01a0 dyld3::closure::Image::forEachImageToInitBefore(void (unsigned int, bool&) block_pointer) const + 86
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff713a6641 dyld3::AllImages::loadImage(Diagnostics&, unsigned int, dyld3::closure::DlopenClosure const*, bool, bool, bool, bool) + 719
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff713a137b dyld3::AllImages::dlopen(Diagnostics&, char const*, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, void const*) + 943
10  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff713a0e8b dyld3::dlopen_internal(char const*, int, void*) + 206
11  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff713a0d53 dlopen + 116
12  libeToken.dylib                 0x000000010dc00b4f init_openssl_crypto + 23
13  libeToken.dylib                 0x000000010dbd99cc dll_Init + 33
14  libeToken.dylib                 0x000000010dc5f47e dll_init_unix + 28
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff713a06d2 invocation function for block in dyld3::AllImages::runAllInitializersInImage(dyld3::closure::Image const*, dyld3::MachOLoaded const*) + 159
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff713a05ae dyld3::closure::Image::forEachInitializer(void const*, void (void const*) block_pointer) const + 84
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff713a0325 invocation function for block in dyld3::AllImages::runInitialzersBottomUp(dyld3::closure::Image const*) + 349
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff713a01a0 dyld3::closure::Image::forEachImageToInitBefore(void (unsigned int, bool&) block_pointer) const + 86
19  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff713a6641 dyld3::AllImages::loadImage(Diagnostics&, unsigned int, dyld3::closure::DlopenClosure const*, bool, bool, bool, bool) + 719
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff713a137b dyld3::AllImages::dlopen(Diagnostics&, char const*, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, void const*) + 943
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff713a0e8b dyld3::dlopen_internal(char const*, int, void*) + 206
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff713a0d53 dlopen + 116
23  ssh                             0x000000010da975fe 0x10d92b000 + 1492478
24  ssh                             0x000000010d93cd1a 0x10d92b000 + 72986
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff713b5cc9 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreAnalytics::Client
0   libsystem_notify.dylib          0x00007fff715a9a7f 0x7fff715a1000 + 35455
1   libsystem_notify.dylib          0x00007fff715a8221 0x7fff715a1000 + 29217
2   libsystem_notify.dylib          0x00007fff715a39b2 notify_register_mach_port + 1801
3   libsystem_notify.dylib          0x00007fff715a310c notify_register_dispatch + 161
4   com.apple.analyticsd            0x00007fff4ecdae67 void applesauce::dispatch::v1::async<void applesauce::dispatch::ManagedObject<CoreAnalytics::Client>::execute_wrapped<CoreAnalytics::Client::init()::$_1>(CoreAnalytics::Client::init()::$_1&&) const::'lambda'()>(dispatch_queue_s*, CoreAnalytics::Client::init()::$_1&&)::'lambda'(void*)::__invoke(void*) + 275
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff7135c658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff71361c44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff713625d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff7136bc09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff715b6a3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff715b5b77 start_wqthread + 15

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x000000010de1bdc0  rcx: 0x00007ffee22c9d08  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000603  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007ffee22c9d30  rsp: 0x00007ffee22c9d08
   r8: 0x0000000000000075   r9: 0x000000000000001c  r10: 0x000000010de1bdc0  r11: 0x0000000000000246
  r12: 0x0000000000000603  r13: 0x00007ffee22c9e00  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000000000016
  rip: 0x00007fff714fd33a  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x00007fff97b633e8

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x10d92b000 -        0x10daf1fc7  ssh (3.0 - 1) <6ADD9552-3ED3-3DD2-85D4-712666449A54> /usr/bin/ssh
       0x10dbca000 -        0x10dc6eff3 +libeToken.dylib (0) <BB031BBF-4ACA-3BE3-950C-24E0AE821211> /Library/Frameworks/eToken.framework/Versions/A/libeToken.dylib
       0x10dd51000 -        0x10dde2eff  dyld (750.5) <1F893B81-89A5-3502-8510-95B97B9F730D> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff2a3f9000 -     0x7fff2a3faff7  libCyrillicConverter.dylib (76) <FC120C56-96EB-37A9-A344-48452B43BA78> /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libCyrillicConverter.dylib
    0x7fff3307f000 -     0x7fff3307ffff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.11 - Accelerate 1.11) <8BE0965F-6A6A-35B0-89D0-F0A75835C2CA> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff33097000 -     0x7fff336edfef  com.apple.vImage (8.1 - 524.2) <DAE0E5C5-BA70-325D-8B4C-6B821F009CBF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff336ee000 -     0x7fff33955ff7  libBLAS.dylib (1303.60.1) <4E980D6B-4B3A-33D6-B52C-AFC7D120D11A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff33956000 -     0x7fff33e29fef  libBNNS.dylib (144.100.2) <C05F9F9D-4498-37BD-9C1C-2F7B920B401D> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBNNS.dylib
    0x7fff33e2a000 -     0x7fff341c5fff  libLAPACK.dylib (1303.60.1) <F8E9D081-7C60-32EC-A47D-2D30CAD73C5F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff341c6000 -     0x7fff341dbfec  libLinearAlgebra.dylib (1303.60.1) <79CB28C5-F811-3EAF-AD8E-7D7D879FE662> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
    0x7fff341dc000 -     0x7fff341e1ff3  libQuadrature.dylib (7) <EB7C9E98-D1E7-314C-90B4-3EB04428CC7C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libQuadrature.dylib
    0x7fff341e2000 -     0x7fff34252fff  libSparse.dylib (103) <8C55F5F2-6AE3-393C-B2FF-22B8CFCBD7FC> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparse.dylib
    0x7fff34253000 -     0x7fff34265fef  libSparseBLAS.dylib (1303.60.1) <08F6D629-5DAC-3A99-B261-2B6095DD38B4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparseBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff34266000 -     0x7fff3443dfd7  libvDSP.dylib (735.100.4) <0744F29B-F822-3571-9B4A-B592146D4E03> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fff3443e000 -     0x7fff34500fef  libvMisc.dylib (735.100.4) <E6C94B52-931B-3858-AF4D-C2EA52ACB7F5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff34501000 -     0x7fff34501fff  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib (3.11 - vecLib 3.11) <66282197-81EE-316F-978E-EF1471551DEF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff35c62000 -     0x7fff35ff0ffd  com.apple.CFNetwork (1125.2 - 1125.2) <1D4D81F7-FC48-3588-87FC-481E2586E345> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff373eb000 -     0x7fff3786affb  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1675.129) <9E632A1E-9622-33D6-BCCE-23AC16DAA6B7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff387d3000 -     0x7fff387d3fff  com.apple.CoreServices (1069.22 - 1069.22) <888FE7B9-CE6C-3C7C-BA33-63364462228A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff387d4000 -     0x7fff38859fff  com.apple.AE (838.1 - 838.1) <2BAB1B88-C198-3D20-8DA3-056E66510E7A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff3885a000 -     0x7fff38b3bff7  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1217 - 1217) <D0FECC17-7E16-308F-98EA-AF311CB77FE6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff38b3c000 -     0x7fff38b89ffd  com.apple.DictionaryServices (1.2 - 323.6) <11513ED9-8B4B-39BB-A6B2-AA6AA0A2DF72> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff38b8a000 -     0x7fff38b92ff7  com.apple.CoreServices.FSEvents (1268.100.1 - 1268.100.1) <CE3D8B13-2583-3527-8532-D5DDAAD7D56B> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents
    0x7fff38b93000 -     0x7fff38dccffc  com.apple.LaunchServices (1069.22 - 1069.22) <E51EE658-608C-3034-9635-4FDF1E241E62> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
    0x7fff38dcd000 -     0x7fff38e65ff1  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 2076.3) <EE42CCA1-FEC2-3F1C-9B62-2E73EFB05FCC> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff38e66000 -     0x7fff38e93fff  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices (1069.22 - 1069.22) <A0654B4E-3194-3066-911F-FF1FBEE1D2C2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fff38e94000 -     0x7fff38efbfff  com.apple.SearchKit (1.4.1 - 1.4.1) <D4F82BC9-FD9B-3E04-B78E-D9E2A73B0BD7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff38efc000 -     0x7fff38f20ff5  com.apple.coreservices.SharedFileList (131.4 - 131.4) <AEB4E42C-F5A2-3F63-80B0-4226483AD4F5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SharedFileList.framework/Versions/A/SharedFileList
    0x7fff39766000 -     0x7fff3976cfff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.7 - 2.7) <D7617B57-B01C-3848-8818-593FB12039E9> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fff39aa1000 -     0x7fff39e66ff8  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1675.129) <9A74FA97-7F7B-3929-B381-D9514B1E4754> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff39ed3000 -     0x7fff39f23ff7  com.apple.GSS (4.0 - 2.0) <16DE732E-4A48-3C8A-BD61-8AF810F3A48C> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/Versions/A/GSS
    0x7fff3a1da000 -     0x7fff3a27eff3  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1726.100.16) <3D8BA34A-AAF7-3AF2-9B5B-189AC4755404> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff3bd92000 -     0x7fff3bda4ff3  com.apple.Kerberos (3.0 - 1) <DC673FF3-4DC9-3C23-9718-343AB36B2984> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
    0x7fff3bda5000 -     0x7fff3bda5fff  libHeimdalProxy.dylib (77) <A970C7A8-7CCD-3701-A459-078BD5E8FE4E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libHeimdalProxy.dylib
    0x7fff3dd7d000 -     0x7fff3dd89ffe  com.apple.NetFS (6.0 - 4.0) <7A96A8FE-17F3-3850-8E81-9DDDC5A48DDB> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
    0x7fff4096b000 -     0x7fff40987fff  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory (10.15 - 220.40.1) <58835104-9E7A-32E8-862B-530CE899C9B4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
    0x7fff40988000 -     0x7fff40993ffd  com.apple.OpenDirectory (10.15 - 220.40.1) <D846BA35-59A1-3B78-B1C8-7E0EDE972AD2> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
    0x7fff42113000 -     0x7fff4211dffb  com.apple.pcsc (8.0 - 1) <1717ED4B-8006-38AB-9570-1B90E8E556A4> /System/Library/Frameworks/PCSC.framework/Versions/A/PCSC
    0x7fff43d2d000 -     0x7fff44076ff1  com.apple.security (7.0 - 59306.101.1) <430E04FE-F068-3476-9CA2-72CB5F040D1F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
    0x7fff44077000 -     0x7fff440ffffb  com.apple.securityfoundation (6.0 - 55236.60.1) <BC15B825-955D-33CF-B416-A64D69A1D008> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
    0x7fff4412e000 -     0x7fff44132ff8  com.apple.xpc.ServiceManagement (1.0 - 1) <C66FC9CF-224B-348C-94A5-ABAC579F5C0A> /System/Library/Frameworks/ServiceManagement.framework/Versions/A/ServiceManagement
    0x7fff44ddd000 -     0x7fff44e4bff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.19 - 1.19) <71AC15DE-7018-3D2B-B599-F2972F0288AE> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff48da8000 -     0x7fff48e6dff7  com.apple.APFS (1412.101.1 - 1412.101.1) <2F5A48FB-9788-3A24-87FE-C1B7DDBC8A07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/APFS.framework/Versions/A/APFS
    0x7fff4acf2000 -     0x7fff4ad01fd7  com.apple.AppleFSCompression (119.100.1 - 1.0) <E1B024EB-DAB1-30A1-A43D-01D9E9357F2B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleFSCompression.framework/Versions/A/AppleFSCompression
    0x7fff4b283000 -     0x7fff4b2a5fff  com.apple.applesauce (1.0 - 16.25) <A6C6D37B-9AA5-3137-A02E-F61798A908B0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSauce.framework/Versions/A/AppleSauce
    0x7fff4c4c0000 -     0x7fff4c4c9ff7  com.apple.coreservices.BackgroundTaskManagement (1.0 - 104) <2088BC70-5329-3390-A851-C4ECF654047C> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackgroundTaskManagement.framework/Versions/A/BackgroundTaskManagement
    0x7fff4e172000 -     0x7fff4e182ffb  com.apple.CommonAuth (4.0 - 2.0) <E09BBBBE-ECDD-3442-8D4E-27A12F5E2347> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonAuth.framework/Versions/A/CommonAuth
    0x7fff4ecd9000 -     0x7fff4ecf8ffc  com.apple.analyticsd (1.0 - 1) <F33987F5-A14A-3A55-8D26-FDE9A57B9269> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAnalytics.framework/Versions/A/CoreAnalytics
    0x7fff4f27f000 -     0x7fff4f28fff3  com.apple.CoreEmoji (1.0 - 107) <AC83B860-61BD-384E-81BF-CA3CBE655968> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreEmoji.framework/Versions/A/CoreEmoji
    0x7fff4f8cf000 -     0x7fff4f939ff0  com.apple.CoreNLP (1.0 - 213) <687A4C31-A307-3255-83BE-9B123971FF62> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreNLP.framework/Versions/A/CoreNLP
    0x7fff507b4000 -     0x7fff507e2ffd  com.apple.CSStore (1069.22 - 1069.22) <39E431F9-3584-34DF-A64D-C5895AA72068> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesStore.framework/Versions/A/CoreServicesStore
    0x7fff59e2a000 -     0x7fff59ee8ff4  com.apple.Heimdal (4.0 - 2.0) <C4838DCE-48FB-3828-9FB2-097BA2848C99> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Heimdal.framework/Versions/A/Heimdal
    0x7fff5ca0d000 -     0x7fff5cadbffd  com.apple.LanguageModeling (1.0 - 215.1) <3FAF1700-F7D4-3F92-88AA-A3920702B8BB> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/Versions/A/LanguageModeling
    0x7fff5cadc000 -     0x7fff5cb24fff  com.apple.Lexicon-framework (1.0 - 72) <212D02CE-11BC-3C7F-BDFD-DF1A0C4017EE> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Lexicon.framework/Versions/A/Lexicon
    0x7fff5cb2b000 -     0x7fff5cb30ff3  com.apple.LinguisticData (1.0 - 353.18) <BA3869B7-9C39-32DA-A4BA-12F1BC4B04CF> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LinguisticData.framework/Versions/A/LinguisticData
    0x7fff5de97000 -     0x7fff5dee3fff  com.apple.spotlight.metadata.utilities (1.0 - 2076.3) <EF8AC054-B15F-375F-AACB-018DC73CD16E> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MetadataUtilities.framework/Versions/A/MetadataUtilities
    0x7fff5e998000 -     0x7fff5e9a2fff  com.apple.NetAuth (6.2 - 6.2) <D324C7CC-E614-35F6-8619-DECBE90ECAEB> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetAuth.framework/Versions/A/NetAuth
    0x7fff67c02000 -     0x7fff67c12ff3  com.apple.TCC (1.0 - 1) <AEE98D6E-03FD-3C80-90AC-5B45B4AE7A2E> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/Versions/A/TCC
    0x7fff68383000 -     0x7fff68384fff  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 33) <F1A2A150-97C1-3050-93EE-6D582E2DF23E> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff6b2dd000 -     0x7fff6b2dfff3  com.apple.loginsupport (1.0 - 1) <B84ABC31-431B-3F99-BABE-44ED0A7DB3C0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/login.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/loginsupport.framework/Versions/A/loginsupport
    0x7fff6ddf8000 -     0x7fff6de2cfff  libCRFSuite.dylib (48) <E52BECF7-1819-3998-ACC4-8D1A332CE4EB> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
    0x7fff6de2f000 -     0x7fff6de39fff  libChineseTokenizer.dylib (34) <EE842A48-3D30-34B0-B9D2-F045DE582650> /usr/lib/libChineseTokenizer.dylib
    0x7fff6dec5000 -     0x7fff6dec7ff7  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (112) <BE749883-9400-334A-8FBF-F3321CF205F5> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff6e39b000 -     0x7fff6e39cfff  libSystem.B.dylib (1281.100.1) <DB8310F1-272D-3533-A840-3B390AF55C26> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff6e429000 -     0x7fff6e42afff  libThaiTokenizer.dylib (3) <DC582222-7C1F-3C27-8C3A-BAF696A2197D> /usr/lib/libThaiTokenizer.dylib
    0x7fff6e442000 -     0x7fff6e458fff  libapple_nghttp2.dylib (1.39.2) <268F4E3E-95DC-35FB-82DC-5B0D1855A676> /usr/lib/libapple_nghttp2.dylib
    0x7fff6e48d000 -     0x7fff6e4ffff7  libarchive.2.dylib (72.100.1) <65E0870E-02AB-365D-84F9-5800B5BB69FC> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
```

...

Comment: Have you asked the developer of `eToken.framework` to provide a versioned `libeToken.dylib` - which the error also is about ?? `Invalid dylib load. Clients should not load the unversioned libcrypto dylib as it does not have a stable ABI`

Comment: I sent a request, but I’m not sure that I will get an answer

Comment: I don't know if this post can help you, which is the same issue, just with Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58272830/python-crashing-on-macos-10-15-beta-19a582a-with-usr-lib-libcrypto-dylib - remember to take backup of what you modify.

Comment: Yes, export different path solved this issue, thanks


export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH